# In PyCharm terminal "git branch -a" shows remote git (Github) repositories that are deleted

Tags: git, github, pycharm

[image]

Created a GitHub repository for a PyCharm Project by using the VCS option in PyCharm. After that, another branch was created with the name Pytest-bdd. Now the repository itself is manually deleted from Github. But when the command `git branch -a` is run from PyCharm terminal it shows the below options

1. `* master`
2. `remotes/github/Pytest-bdd`
3. `remotes/github/master`

Why does it show remote repository when it does not exist in Github anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR: delete the remote

If the *entire repository* is deleted, you should delete the *remote:*

```
git remote remove github
```

This also removes all of the remote-tracking names that go with that remote.

#### Long: remotes and remote-tracking names

When working with Git, you often work with two, or even more than two, Git repositories.  Each repository exists in some location on some computer.  A file or other resource that exists on some computer can often be named using a Uniform Resource Locator or [*URL*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

So if you have a Git repository on GitHub under the name `https://github.com/user/repo.git`, for instance, this is a *URL* for this repository.  You *could* type this string in every time you want your own Git, on your own computer, to call up the Git on GitHub that is in charge of *that* repository over on GitHub.  But it's easier to type in a short name:

```
git fetch origin
```

than the longer one:

```
git fetch https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

This short name, `origin`, is a *remote*.  A remote, in Git, stores a URL.  It can do more, but storing a URL is its most basic job.

When you first *clone* some existing repository, Git adds the remote name `origin` to hold the URL you used in your `git clone` command.  So it's pretty common for your own Git, on your own computer, to have an `origin`.

You can add more remotes.  First, you need to come up with a *name* you want to use, such as [`hubert-blaine-wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff-sr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff_Sr.) or `fred` or `github` or `upstream`.  Shorter names are probably better, but you should use one that *means something to you*.  Next, you need a URL at which some Git repository answers the Internet-phone when you call it up.  You then use `git remote add` to *add* the remote-and-URL pair:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/user2/repo2.git
```

for instance.

When you use `git fetch`, you have your Git call up some other Git.  If you use a *remote* to name the other Git, your Git fishes the URL out of your Git configuration files and uses that to phone-up the other Git.  The other Git will list, for your Git, *its* branch names.  Your Git, at the end of the `git fetch` session, will create in *your* repository, a series of similar names.

To avoid stepping on your *branch* names, your Git creates their branch names, in your repository, using *remote-tracking names*.  To turn their *branch* name into your *remote-tracking* name, your Git sticks your *remote* name, such as `origin` or `upstream`, in front of their *branch* name.  So their `master` becomes your `origin/master`, or `upstream/master`, or `github/master`.

Internally, *all* of these names have long (or full name) forms: instead of `master`, for instance, your own `master` branch is really `refs/heads/master`.  The `origin/master` here is short for `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  Git normally takes away these prefixes so that you do not have to see them or type them in.

When you run `git branch -r`, your Git will list these remote-tracking names.  When you run `git branch` or `git branch -l`, your Git will list your *branch* names.  When you use `git branch -a`, your Git will list *both*, but this time, instead of shortening remote-tracking names to, e.g., `origin/master`, your Git will shorten them to `remotes/origin/master`.

This is what you show in the image you put up at the top of your question.  The *branch* name `master`—an original name in *your* repository—is in green; the *remote-tracking names*—their branch names, but modified by your Git to fit in *your* repository—are in red.

Since the repository on GitHub is entirely gone, all these red-text remote-tracking names are useless now.  You *can* delete them, one by one, from your own Git repository.  But since the repository on GitHub is entirely gone, the *remote* name `github` itself is also useless.  Rather than painstakingly deleting each remote-tracking name, and leaving the remote itself behind, you can just delete the remote entirely.  Deleting the remote deletes all of your own Git's remote-tracking names *copied from* that remote, so one delete will do everything.

Comment: Wow!! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, I'm sure others will appreciate it too!.

Answer (score 1):

Those are "remote-tracking branches" https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches. They remember what the "remote looked like as of the last time you communicated with it," meaning that they don't get updated in real time by what you do to the remote through other means, e.g. by deleting the repo on GitHub.

If you want to clean this stuff up from your local repository, do these two things:

1. delete these remote-tracking branches
2. remove the remote (probably)

Comment: If I use the command ""git push origin --delete <name> it generates an error saying "remote: Repository not found"  which is right because I have manually deleted it from github . So how to delete those ?
@guest

Comment: oh use `git branch --delete --remotes github/Pytest-bdd`. the one you said tries to tell the remote to delete theirs too, which fails because they don't know of the repo anymore

Comment: Thank u very much . It worked !! . So what is this *master . Is it the master branch in the local repository?

Comment: yeah, it's that